# javascript ajax response in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to call a legacy system which returns the following response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var responseObj = {
   success: ('0'=='0'),
   cfgInfo: {
        deletedId: ''
   },
   data: {
          id:"9470",devicePIFrom:"10.10.10.34",devicePIFromAlias:"10.10.10.34",
          deviceCommunityRW:"",deviceCommunityRO:"H1ghL!ght",devicePIUseProxy:"1",
          devicePITo:"10.10.10.10",devicePIToAlias:"Fake  local server",
          devicePISrcIP:"6.6.6.6",piStyle:"ICMPPing",SLAdelay:"100",
          devicePIToPort:"0",piWanted:"1",piAutoClasses:"",piNocDisabled:"",
          piCtrlPacketSize:'50',piTestInterval:'0',piProbeInterval:'',piProbeCount:'',
      piMOSCodec:'0',pimosSLA:'3.5',piSLAPacketLoss:'0.05',piSLAJitter:'20'
   },
   errors: [

   ]
}
</script>
```

My jquery looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: requestString,
            dataType: 'script',
                    success: function(data){
                    .....do stuff......
                    }
});
```

How can I get at the responseObj given that I cannot change the legacy system's response format?

Comment: it looks like you have to write your own parser because that thing almost looks like JSON BUT the `success: ('0'=='0')` is not valid json ans so is `cfgInfo:` because of the missing "" (it should be like that: `"cfgInfo"`. for more information about json look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: here is one parser i found: http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2009/01/22/jsreg-javascript-parser/ you could also write your own or just search for an open source parser. you could also use ANTLR http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3JavaScriptTarget BUT therefore you'd have to know how to write an EBNF grammar.

Comment: This code should work if the response didn't have `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` around it.  jQuery would execute and `responseObj` would become global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help - in the end ext-js gave me the answer:

using
    var response = eval("(" + data + ')');
to process the response string yields the javascript object - I can then access the properties directly as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: requestString,
dataType: 'script',
    success: function(data){
   var response = eval("(" + data + ')');
       if(response.success) {
           ...do stuff.....
       }
    }
});
```

obscure but it works!